# Securing SOAP webservice, wildfly, authentication error

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, soap, jax-ws, wildfly

I've got a jax-ws webservice which I need to secure. When I start wildfly everything seems to load nicely, but when I try to send a request via SOAPUI tool, the server returns Error with body element - unauthorized. Relevant parts of code below.

Webservice itself:

```
@WebService
@Stateless
@RolesAllowed("testrole")
@SecurityDomain("test-domain")
public class Test {

    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(name = "HelloResponse")
    public String sayHello(@WebParam(name = "username") String name) {
        return "Hello " + name;
    }
}
```

standalone.xml:

```
<security-domain name="test-domain" cache-type="default">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UserRolesLoginModule"
            flag="required">

            <module-option name="userProperties" value="test-domain-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="test-domain-roles.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

jboss-web.xml:

```
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>test-domain</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

test-domain-users.properties and test-domain-roles.properties look like this:
testuser=testpassword, testuser=testrole

Comment: How do you send credentials from your client?

Comment: Post the actual response here.

Comment: The response is <html>
   <head>
      <title>Error</title>
   </head>
   <body>Unauthorized</body>
</html> 
my wild guess is that I have those properties files in a wrong directory, does anyone know where should I put them?

Comment: Adding to what @JohnAment asks, how are you passing the credentials for `testuser` from SoapUI? Post the SOAP request and any associated configuration for authentication.  I suspect if you are not passing credentials at all (or not in the way wildfly expects) you will get an unauthorized response.

Comment: @mcjkwlczk - what have U done? How did U fix this? Answer.